# VBA Msgbox - No Default Button

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if it's possile to show a Msgbox in VBA (Excel 2007), without any button being set as default?
I have a yes\no button and I don't want the user to hit return or the space bar and accidentally trigger a default button.

Anyone know if this is possible so that neither button on my form is set to default, forcing the user to click yes or no?

```
If MsgBox("Message goes here", vbYesNo + vbQuestion ) = vbYes Then
    'Something
Else
    'Else
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible unfortunately.

A (not particularly nice) workaround would be to code the message box using a UserForm. Probably not worth doing given the benefit over the extra code you'd have to maintain.

Comment: I thought as much. And yes, agree that using a UserForm is overkill unless absolutely necessary. Thx.

Answer (score 9):

Another workaround (other than a UserForm, or trapping <kbd>Enter</kbd> & <kbd>Space</kbd> etc) is to

1. Add a third button option that is an invalid choice
2. Make this button the default
3. Continue to show the message box if this option is picked

*code*

```
Dim lngMsg As Long
Do
lngMsg = MsgBox("Message goes here (Yes or No)", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton3)
Loop While lngMsg = vbCancel
If lngMsg = vbYes Then
' route a
Else
' route b
End If
```

Comment: thx. I did go with this and ended up adding a cancel button which works just as well.

Comment: So than this is accepted answer. Btw nice idea @brettdj

Answer (score -1):

```
If MsgBox("Message goes here", vbYesNo + vbQuestion **+ vbDefaultButton2**) = vbYes Then
    'Something
Else
    'Else
End If
```